# ClojureScript google closure code splitting partial loading

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure, om

I'm coming from a javascript/react/react-router/webpack background to a clojurescript/om environment.

With webpack & react-router it was possible to split my code and only load the javascript needed. E.g. on /login I would only load the js necessary to display the login-page everything else would be left out.

How do I the same with clojurescript/om?
Apparently it's possible to split your code into multiple files: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#modules

The question is how do I only load the code necessary to render the current page: /login for example...
With webpack I would manually write `require.ensure` to asynchronously load the necessary javascript to render a certain page. React Router supports this very well.
Is there any equivalent in clojurescript without making multiple html files and each giving it the right script tag with the splitted code through google closure modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I don't have a concrete example yet, and I agree that webpack and react-router make this really easy. There are some links that may direct you to get it working:

- Code splitting: http://swannodette.github.io/2015/02/23/hello-google-closure-modules

  - Manually adding script tags to html files
  - Actual docs: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#modules
- Dynamic loading of cljs modules: https://rasterize.io/blog/cljs-dynamic-module-loading.html

  - Uses multi-methods for route definitions to dynamically add implementations when loading more code
  - Dense read, there is no easy tooling regarding this use case right now, but the article has all clues to get it working

I hope this helps. If you get around to implementing this in an OSS example it would be great if you could share the link.

Comment: I found that blogpost in the meantime. I'll make an OSS example out of it as soon as I find the time! Thanks for the response

Comment: Nice! That would be awesome!